# Toggle button in tabbed pane Blackberry 10 QNX

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I would like to know if it is possible to add a toggle button to a tabbed pane. Here is some code to explain the issue:

```
TabbedPane {
    showTabsOnActionBar: false
    Tab {
        title: qsTr("Some tab") + Retranslate.onLocaleOrLanguageChanged
        //Adding a toggle button here causes an error
    } 
}
```

I would like the tab to display "Some tab" and next to it there should be a toggle button. The toggle button would represent some setting. If this is not possible, how would you suggest that I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The other tab can be this:

```
Tab {
    title: "Tab 2"
    property variant toggle: false
    onTriggered: {
        console.log("YOU TRIGGERED! " +toggle)
        title = "Tab X"
        toggle = !toggle;
    }
}
```

Now you can change image and title from there, and everything the button does.